# how to automatic insert new row to table when new row of another table is inserted in excel

Tags: excel

I have 3 table in the same sheet in Excel, and these tables in the same row. These tables also have the same column(id). And I want whenever I insert new row in first table, new row will be inserted in others table. But I don't know how to do it or key word to google it. 
Please give me advice.
(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Please add some example code. It will be easier for people to analyse your issue and help you.

Comment: Could you please upload a few screenshots for us to better understand the problem: (1) a screenshot of what you currently have and (2) a mock-up of your desired / expected outcome or behavior. While you probably do not have enough reputation to append the pictures to your original post you could still upload them to http://imgur.com/ and then post the link to the pictures here. This would help us better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If all 3 tables are in the same sheet then if you add a row, it will be added across all tables. Probably you mean something different. 
1. Do you want to add only cells in 1 table and then in same row should be added cells to another table?
2. Are all 3 tables really in same sheet? You write they have same ColumnID, then it looks like they are in different sheets.
3. Do you want to offset the borders only in 2 tables according to adding of the row in 1st table?
4. Are you capable of using a macro?
You need to specify your problem better or put a printscreen to better understand your problem.